# evenly spacing 4 or 5 buttons, depending on the user device

Tags: ios, user-interface, uibutton, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to create a user interface for both iPad and iPhone in storyboard. The iphone version has 1 button less. All buttons and helper views are pinned to the bottomLayouGuide. Also, I am using hidden helper views to evenly split the buttons. Hidden helper views have `equalWidth Constraint` active and each one is pinned to the left and right button. The result of this restrictions is the bottom image showing the ipad version

[image]

The problem arises when I want to eliminate 1 button and still have my button evenly split. Is there variation of the approach described earlier to achieve evenly spaced buttons even if 1 button is missing? If not, what approach do you recommend for evenly spacing 4 or 5 buttons, depending on the device running the app?. The only think that must be satisfied is that the buttons are pinned to the bottom layout guide, because of animations applied to them in the app.

Comment: what happened if you remove the last button and helper view for the iPhone layout?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using UIButtons?  If so, you could potentially use a collection view instead of buttons.  It might be a bit easier in your case to just update the collection view layout rather than managing a dynamic view hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is to restrict the installation only to certain layouts.

The way I would do this is to first put the view in the compact width, any layout.

[image: Show how to set layout.]

Then layout the buttons and positioning views for the iPhone.

Then set the layout for regular width and any height.

Install all the buttons, views and constraints except for the one that pins the last view to the end of the main view.

Then add the 5th button and an extra view with the required constraints to pin it properly.

[image: Where to set installations.]